# What are some tips on growing strawberries from seed?

Tags: strawberries, seed-starting

I have a reasonable amount of practice growing things from seed but I recently spread a whole packet of strawberry seed at the right depth and didn't get a single sprouter.

I'm hoping to get some pro-tips on how to grow strawberry from seed.

The packet said I could grow them in place so I didn't try growing in trays.

I live in Sydney Australia and the temperature here has been in the mid 20s with a reasonable amount of rain.

If you have had experience growing strawberries from seed can you give me some suggestions.

Comment: I assume that is mid 20s Celsius? Not fahrenheit!?

Comment: If it's raining ice by the ocean I don't think you are growing strawberries XD (I'm sure he/she means 20 C)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the type of strawberry seed they may need cold stratification for 2-3 months. This can be done by having the seeds in the fridge during this time.

Answer (score 0):

Growing strawberries from seed can be a rewarding and cost-effective way to establish your strawberry patch. While it may take a bit more time and patience compared to purchasing and planting bare root plants or seedlings, following these tips will help you successfully grow strawberries from seed:

Seed selection: Choose high-quality, disease-resistant strawberry seeds from a reputable source. Select the desired variety based on factors such as flavor, fruit size, and climate suitability.

Indoor sowing: Start your strawberry seeds indoors approximately 8-10 weeks before the last expected frost date. This allows the seedlings enough time to grow and become established before transplanting outdoors.

Proper germination environment: Use a seed starting mix or a soilless potting mix to fill your seed trays or containers. Moisten the mix before sowing the seeds. Sow the seeds on the surface of the mix and lightly press them into the soil. Do not cover them with soil, as strawberry seeds require light to germinate.

Temperature and light: Maintain a consistent temperature of 60-75°F (16-24°C) during germination. Place the containers in a sunny spot or use a grow light to provide at least 12 hours of light per day. Keep the soil moist but not waterlogged.

Patience during germination: Strawberry seeds may take 2-6 weeks to germinate, so be patient. You can cover the containers with a plastic wrap to help maintain humidity, but remove the cover once the seedlings emerge.

Seedling care: Once the seedlings have developed two to three true leaves, transplant them into individual containers filled with a well-draining potting mix. Continue to provide adequate light and maintain consistent moisture levels.

Hardening off: Gradually acclimate the seedlings to outdoor conditions by placing them outside for a few hours each day, gradually increasing the duration over a week or two. Ensure the seedlings are protected from harsh sun, wind, or rain during this process.

Outdoor transplanting: Transplant your strawberry seedlings outdoors once the danger of frost has passed and they have been hardened off. Plant the seedlings in a prepared bed with well-draining soil, full sun exposure, and proper spacing for the chosen variety.

Fertilization and watering: Apply a balanced, slow-release fertilizer at planting time and again in early summer. Provide consistent moisture by watering 1-2 inches per week, either through rainfall or supplemental irrigation.

Mulching: Use organic mulch, such as straw or pine needles, to help conserve moisture, suppress weeds, and regulate soil temperature around your strawberry plants.

Pest and disease control: Regularly inspect your plants for signs of pests or diseases and address any issues promptly using appropriate organic or chemical controls.

By following these tips and dedicating time and patience to the process, you can successfully grow strawberries from seed and enjoy the satisfaction of cultivating your own delicious, homegrown berries. Happy gardening!

The above answer, which provides tips on successfully growing strawberries from seed, was based on the extensive article published on [gardenfrontier.com](https://gardenfrontier.com/cultivate-perfect-sequoia-strawberry/).

Drawing from the valuable information and expert advice presented in the article, the response outlines the key steps for cultivating healthy, fruitful strawberry plants from seed, including seed selection, indoor sowing, germination, seedling care, and transplanting.

By applying the insights from this comprehensive resource, gardeners can confidently embark on their strawberry-growing journey and enjoy the satisfaction of harvesting their own homegrown berries.

Comment: Are you affiliated with this site?

Comment: This looks like Chat-GPT output.